# Inserting html inside string variable used in React component

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

I have a react app I am building for my portfolio site. Currently i have the app written in JSX so i can add stuff like:

```
class Project extends React.Component {
render() {
    return (
        <div className={this.props.project.class}>
            <h1>{this.props.project.header}</h1>
            <div>
                <div className='description'>
                    <p>{this.props.project.description}</p>
                    <p>The Tech Stack</p>
                    <ul>
                        {
                        this.props.project.items.map(function(listValue){
                            return <li>{listValue}</li>;
                        })}
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div className='image'>

                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    );
}
```

}

to my component. I am currently managing my long strings of text in a different file called Text.js:

```
export let exampleText = "Graded is a application developed by <a href='google.com'> Link here. </a> and myself for our second year user interfaces course.";
```

And access it in my jsx file here:

```
var gradedItems = {
    class: "gradedSection content",
    header: "Graded",
    description: Text.exampleText,
    items : ["Java", "Android"]
}
```

and then it gets displayed in the `<p>` tags in the above component. However as I mentioned the link doesn't actually render and the html tags don't get rendered. So it looks like some text and then a  tag in the website.

How should I go about adding these html tags within this string so when the component renders it, the html elements inside get rendered out?

Is it even possible in this situation, is there a better way of doing what I'm trying to achieve?

Thanks as always SO!

Comment: There's also a package to avoid `dangerouslySet`, https://github.com/utatti/react-render-html, and there are a few others that do the same thing.

Comment: Yeah render-html was the easiest solution. Thanks @Dave

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An option is to change the strings in `Text.js` to html bits, like

```
export const exampleText = (
  <span>
    Graded is a application developed by 
    <a href='google.com'> Link here. </a>
    and myself for our second year user interfaces course.
  </span>
);
```

Answer (score 5):

You just need to use [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) and it will help.

Example usage:

```
let exampleText = "Graded is a application developed by <a href='google.com'> Link here. </a> and myself for our second year user interfaces course.";
function Component() {
  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: exampleText }} />;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

first you *npm install html-react-parser*

```
import Parser from 'html-react-parser';

var exampleText = 'Graded is a application developed by <a href='google.com'>     Link here. </a> and myself for our second year user interfaces course.';


render: function() {
    return (
        <div>{Parser(exampleText)}</div>
    );
}
```