# Add line break to .js data file in react

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, json, react-hooks

Hi i have a js file which is exporting data to my components how do i make some of the text bold and force a line break? I've tried `\n` but that doesn't work. I've annotated where i want the line break and where i want the text to be bold.

```
export const productData = [
    ...
        desc: "{bold} Heavy on features.Light on price. {line break here} Stay connected. Even without your phone. With powerful features to help keep you connected, active, healthy and safe, Apple Watch SE is a lot of watch for less.",

]
```

Comment: If you are wanting to render to the screen, you'll need to use a JSX object rather than a string and use <br />.

Comment: i'm rendering like this 
```<p className="mt-3 md:mt-6 text-secondary-gray">
        {product.desc}
</p>
```

Comment: Try `desc = (TEXT BEFORE LINE BREAK <br /> TEXT AFTER LINE BREAK);` This creates a JSX tag and supports normal JSX line breaks and so forth.

Comment: @BlakeOttinger that would probably output the text `<br />`, not a br element

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add a <br> tag in reactjs between two strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45935733/how-to-add-a-br-tag-in-reactjs-between-two-strings)

Comment: yeah <br> just outputs it as text

Comment: Please check if [Inserting html inside string variable used in React component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48084149/inserting-html-inside-string-variable-used-in-react-component), and/or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57160503/13658816) is of any help.